# Remapping scancode for Caps Lock

Tags: slackware, key-mapping

In Windows I was able to set Caps Lock to act as a second Enter, which can be pressed by the left little finger. I added this parameter to the registry to do that:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
>   "Scancode
>   Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1c,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00

How can I do the same in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent would be to run the [`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) program each time you log in.

Put the following snippet in a file called `.Xmodmap` in your home directory:

```
keycode 66 = Return
clear Lock
```

You can see the key codes and current associated key names by running [`xev`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) from a terminal. Press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> while the xev window is focused, and you'll see a something like

```
KeyPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x7c00001,
    root 0x105, subw 0x0, time 96597741, (1548,225), root:(3151,256),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"   XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

For most keys, you only need the `keycode` line. Modifiers are tracked separately: you need to match keysyms (what's on the right of the `keycode … = …` directive) with modifiers. The directive `clear Lock` removes the `Lock` modifier (which is Caps Lock or Shift Lock) from all keys.

Depending on your distribution and on your desktop environment, it may or may not be enough to add these lines to `~/.Xmodmap`: many setups, but not all, automatically read this file at login time. If yours doesn't, run the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` at login time. How to do this depends on your choice of desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

in my .Xmodmap file I turn <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Escape</kbd>

```
clear Lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

to turn it into <kbd>Return</kbd> like you want, this would do the trick

```
clear Lock
keycode 0x42 = Return
```

Very interestingly, It can be use for other key combination, for example I have

```
keycode 0x87 = Insert
```

and this turns the <kbd>Context Menu key</kbd> into the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. ( interessing for me of course)

Like Gilles's answer say, you can use `xev` to determine the keycode of the key you want to reassign.

Don't forget that you have to launch:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

in the startup script of the Window Manager of your user so as the key redirection is taken into account for each new session you log in.