# XFCE keyboard layout switcher broke .Xmodmap Caps Lock remapping

Tags: xfce, slackware, key-mapping, startx

I have successfully remapped Caps Lock to Enter, using ~/.Xmodmap:

```
clear Lock
keycode 66 = Return
```

[Remapping scancode for Caps Lock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71612/remapping-scancode-for-caps-lock)

But after switching to XFCE and installing keyboard switching plugin, the remapping is broken. So I have to manually run every time after I login:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just put that line in your `$HOME/.xinitrc` file.

Comment: It's already there: `usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap` ... `if [ -f $usermodmap ]; then
    /usr/bin/xmodmap $usermodmap
fi`

Comment: How do you start your Xfce session?

Comment: I just type: startx, I use Slackware 14.0